# Mixpanel Device Tokens Disappearing

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, mixpanel

I've added MixPanel to my app for push notifications. When my app runs for the first time it requests permission to send notifications and assuming the user clicks "OK" the device token is passed to MixPanel and added to their profile.

In the Explore tab of MixPanel I can see the users device token.

If I create a notification and send it to that user, the device token gets erased from their profile and the notification sends to 0 users.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The Mixpanel push sender removes invalid tokens (standard given APNS/GCM policies about repeated attempts with invalid tokens). The most likely reason for the token to be invalid is that the tokens were not created with the push certificate you're using to send. Try re-uploading your certificate to Mixpanel.

Comment: I am facing similar problem @Joe Green 
Were you able to find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by using the production certificate instead of the sandbox one